# Android news application cant update isFavorite boolean through api

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a news app where you have a home screen with articles loaded from an api and you have a favorite screen with your favorite articles. You can click an article and put it in your favorites and when you navigate to the favorite page, you can select an article and remove it.

I have created a model Article:

```
data class Article(
    @SerializedName("Id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("Title")
    val title: String,
    @SerializedName("PublishDate")
    val publishDate: String,
    @SerializedName("Summary")
    val summary: String,
    @SerializedName("Image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("Url")
    val url: String,
    @SerializedName("IsFavorite")
    var isFavorite: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("Feed")
    val feed: Int,
    @SerializedName("Categories")
    val categories: List<Category>,
    @SerializedName("Related")
    val related: List<String>
)
```

and I am using the "isFavorite" to check if the article is favorite or not. The api requests work fine but in my MainViewModel it goes wrong for some reason:

```
fun favoriteArticle(context: Context) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val getSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val authToken = getSharedPref.getString("AuthToken", "")
            if (!authToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                if (selectedArticle.isFavorite) {
                    articleRepo.deleteLikedArticle(authToken, selectedArticle.id)
                    showMessage(context, R.string.article_removed_favorites)
                } else {
                    articleRepo.addLikedArticle(authToken, selectedArticle.id)
                    showMessage(context, R.string.article_added_favorites)

                }
            }
            refreshListOfArticles(context)
            refreshListOfLikedArticles(context)
        }
    }
```

A friend of mine did almost the same steps and for him this works, but for me it doesnt. The isFavorite stays on false while it should change. Putting in "selectedArticle.isFavorite == true" for example kinda works, but then it adds the article twice and then removes it.

How can I solve this problem?

So I've tried the example above, tried some chatgpt stuff, but can't figure out why its not updating correctly

Maybe this is also nice to add for clearance

```
var listOfArticlesResponse: List<Article> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    var listOfLikedArticlesResponse: List<Article> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    var selectedArticle: Article by mutableStateOf(
        Article(
            id = 0,
            title = "",
            publishDate = "",
            summary = "",
            image = "",
            url = "",
            isFavorite = false,
            feed = 0,
            categories = listOf(),
            related = listOf()
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine

```
articleRepo.addLikedArticle
```

is an asynchronous call? i.e. you do it on a background thread/coroutine?

Therefore if you have the code:

```
articleRepo.addLikedArticle(authToken, selectedArticle.id)
...
refreshListOfArticles(context)
```

it could be that, the refresh happens before the adding of the likes is completed.

You can either, do both on the same coroutine (to guarantee order or execution), or have a callback after the the first adding is complete and then do what you want to do afterward.

Comment: What can I share with you to have it more clear as it's gonna be a lot of code to share I think

Comment: You need to make yourself a minimal viable reproduction. Start a new app and add code bit by bit until you can reproduce it (and you maybe discover the problem yourself whilst doing it)

Comment: Alright will do, thanks!